# Download webpage source HTML without visiting page

Tags: google-chrome, malware

So, I've got a situation with a malicious page. First off, Chrome will not let me visit the page at all. With firefox, it blocks me, but will allow me to ignore the message.

I don't *want* to visit the page though. But I need to figure out what's wrong with it.

**Is it possible to download the HTML source code from the page without viewing it?**

**EDIT:** I'm kinda wondering if there's a site that can do it. I've seen indirect page renderers that view and render the page - wasn't sure if there's a site that can provide a page source downloader. If not though, that's fine - however I can get it will suit me.

Comment: This is possible if you have FTP access or access to the files on the server.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I'm using windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wget or curl, if you're running a *NIX operating system then either of them will be installed already, if not then you can get Windows wget from

```
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
```

or curl from

```
http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
```

You will be 'visiting' the page, but you'll only get the source code, and it won't be rendered at all meaning it's safe to view.

In response to your edit, I suppose you could use this tool -

http://onlinecurl.com/

Comment: If you're using wget you'll do something like:

wget -qO- http://google.com | cat

With curl you can just do:

curl google.com

And the output is the source

Comment: Sweet! Seems a little buggy - I have to refresh the page before using it again, but it seems to work..

Comment: Hm. It seemed to work for all other sites except for that one :-? - It gave me "Content-Size: 0" but I visited the page in FF (with all safety guards up), and it's still a legit page. - Anyway I did get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, create a hyperlink (just copy and paste the url somewhere) then right click and "save link as"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Unfortunately, this does not appear to be a valid solution to the problem (at least so far as I can tell). If you have some particular set of steps in mind, please add them to your answer.

Comment: Whats part is not clear? create a hyperlink?? say in word or something like that, right click the hyperlink and windows gives you the option to save as, thus giving you all the html from the page without having browsed to it. which is what the OP asked.

Comment: Copying and pasting the URL somewhere doesn't automatically allow the option to "Save link as...". If it is a hyperlink on the desktop, for instance, there is no such option. Nor if it is pasted it in Notepad++, OpenOffice or even in Word 2010 (apparently). None of these present any direct "Save link as..." entry. Hence the original comment that there seems to be something missing in the steps provided.